# Why is smaller sized script with async tag is executed second?

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous, tags, script-tag

I am trying to understand the work of async tag.
Suppose I have the following piece of code in my html:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <script src="js/big.js"></script>
    <script src="js/small.js" async></script>
</head>
```

script **big.js** is much larger, and loaded after **small.js** and still executed first, event small.js has the async tag added. Shouldn't **async** tag guarantee that the script is executed as soon as it is downloaded?

Notice: if I put async to big.js script, the **small.js** is executed first.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there are **no guarantees** about the order of execution for async scripts. That said, the behavior you're describing is due to your code itself.

If `big.js` is not loaded using `async`, since it it before `small.js` in the DOM, it is mandated by the spec that it will be executed first. In fact, the browser is not able to execute any additional JavaScript until `big.js` has been executed. This is because scripts loaded without `async` are, well, *not asynchronous*. They're guaranteed to be synchronous.

Note that despite this, `small.js` can still be *downloaded* asynchronously. In fact, browsers can download all resources asynchronously whether or not they're explicitly marked as async. The spec only mandates rules about execution order, nothing more.